# Using the indefinite article after the definite article with the same object

Tags: articles

I came across an ESL short story with an unusual usage of articles:

> Jake was a keen fisherman and at the weekends he often took his boat
>   out to the middle of **the lake** to relax and recover from the hustle and
>   bustle of the working week. One day, Jake was sitting in his boat,
>   enjoying the tranquility of the place. The sun was shining and he was
>   listening to the gentle lapping of the water around his boat.  He
>   noticed a woman walking along by the side of **a lake**. The woman stopped and called out, ‘Hey! You! Are you thinking out there?’...([the full story](http://www.esljokes.net/ui11.html))

Could anybody help me to understand the usage of the articles with the word "lake" in the passage? Isn't that the same "lake" in the both sentences? As I thought we should use "the" with the object which has already been mentioned. Maybe there is another rule in this case?

Comment: Yes, there's a mistake. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: these are a bit anomalous.

The first "the" is a convention of narrative. Even though the lake has not been mentioned before, starting a narrative with a definite phrase like that helps build the sense that we are hearing just one part of a longer story: "the lake" isn't one we know anything about, but it is the one that Jake would refer to as "the lake".

The "a" is odd: it can only mean that she was walking by a different lake; but that doesn't make sense either, so, as Lambie says, I think it is a mistake.